# Sum of elements of subarrays is equal to a target value in Python

Tags: python, recursion, sub-array

I am given with an array `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and a target value `trgt = 10`. I need to find all possible combinations of `subarrays` such that sum of the elements of each subarray will result in the given target value `trgt`. I need to use Python to acomplish the task. I have found a similar discussion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087820/python-subset-sum). However the given solution there only returns only one possible subarray instead of other valid subarrays. Any help pointing to obtaining all such subarrays will be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself yet? It's not a good practice to ask others to do your homework. You can share your approach, upto what extent you were able to work out and where you are actually failing.

Comment: The solution you refer to in your link ___does___ return all valid sub arrays, not only one.

Answer (score 1):

The library  of choice for getting combinations is `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
trgt = 10
```

At first calculate the maximum length of a tuple that could result in `trgt` when summed up, even when it consists of the smallest numbers available:

```
maxsize = np.argwhere(np.cumsum(sorted(arr))>trgt)[0][0]
```

Then iterate from one to `maxsize`, let itertools create the corresponding combinations and save only those which sum up to `trgt`:

```
subsets = []
for size in range(1, maxsize+1):
    subsets.extend([t for t in it.combinations(arr, size) if sum(t)==trgt])

print(subsets)

#[(10,), (1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually I am looking for a solution that does not require to import other libraries. However anyway thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution finds the subsets which adds to a target number:

```
def subsetsum(array,num):

if num == 0 or num < 1:
    return None
elif len(array) == 0:
    return None
else:
    if array[0] == num:
        return [array[0]]
    else:
        with_v = subsetsum(array[1:],(num - array[0])) 
        if with_v:
            return [array[0]] + with_v
        else:
            return subsetsum(array[1:],num)
```

Comment: I have seen this solution before I have even posted the question. And as I mentioned this solution provides only one sunset out of many possible ones. What I wanted instead is all possible subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to generate all solutions, you have solve it using brute force. One way to do this is by using bit masking like below

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
n = len(arr)
target = 10
res = []
for i in range(1<<n):
    s = 0
    subset = []
    for j in range(n):
        if i & (1<<(j)): # if this bit is set to 1
            subset.append(arr[j])
    if sum(subset) == target:
        res.append(subset)
print(res)  # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6], [4, 6], [1, 2, 7], [3, 7], [2, 8], [1, 9], [10]]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you mean by bit masking?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function of @harry on the SO-site of your link:

```
def subset(array, num):
    result = []
    def find(arr, num, path=()):
        if not arr:
            return
        if arr[0] == num:
            result.append(path + (arr[0],))
        else:
            find(arr[1:], num - arr[0], path + (arr[0],))
            find(arr[1:], num, path)
    find(array, num)
    return result
```

This is your data:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
trgt = 10
```

the function from above applied to your data:

```
subset(arr, trgt)
#[(1, 2, 3, 4),
# (1, 2, 7),
# (1, 3, 6),
# (1, 4, 5),
# (1, 9),
# (2, 3, 5),
# (2, 8),
# (3, 7),
# (4, 6),
# (10,)]
```

So I'd suggest you to follow your link, upvote harry's answer and use it.