# Change-making problem with large datasets

Tags: python, loops, data-analysis

Consider a given list of integers and a given target value. By looping over this list, the function tests whether the sum of any subset of the list is equal to the given target value.

```
Input: 
IntegerList = [1, 3, 4, 6, 11, 33, 12]
TargetValue = 13

Output: 
[3, 4, 6]
```

In this case, the function's output reads [3, 4, 6], as these are the values which equal 13.

Many solutions exist to what is called the change-making problem, using Python. See examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087820/python-subset-sum), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305843/find-all-subsets-that-sum-to-a-particular-value). However, these solutions cannot handle my present list, which is roughly 8,000 lines long. It returns the following error:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

My current recursion depth is 3,000. I attempted to increase the recursion depth and crashed the kernel--folks elsewhere suggested that this was ill-advised anyway.

How can I maximize performance in my code to handle larger lists, such as 8,000 or even 80,000 lines?

Comment: Are these integers always positive, or do negative integers also feature in the dataset?

Comment: Clearly you will have to rework the solution to not use recursion (a function calling itself)

Comment: @soyapencil no, these numbers can be positive or negative